# Trouble with MySQL Query - WHERE AND / OR

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

This query generates a list of items per zip code.

```
$ziparrayimplode = implode(",", $ziparray);
        $listingquery = "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE (CONCAT(title, description) LIKE '%".$searchstring."%') AND auc_cat LIKE '%".$category."%' AND zip IN ($ziparrayimplode) AND all_zip=$allzip ORDER BY list_ts DESC $pages->limit";
        $listinghistory = mysql_query($listingquery) or die(mysql_error());
```

If I use "AND" in the WHERE statement for all_zip=$allzip then all the items that are true for all_zip will show, but not the items in $ziparray.  If I use "OR" in the WHERE statement then the items true for $ziparray will be included as well as $allzip... but my search function won't work at all.

Am I phrasing this query correctly or should I use "OR" in the WHERE statement and look for the problem in the way the search is coded?

Comment: Tried using `(` and `)` to group conditions? Also, please learn to use PDO, or at least `mysqli`, `myqsl` is deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manage it playing with OR / AND operators precedence (your strange result seems to show that you're actually a "victim" of wrong usage of operator precedence), or just add parentheses.

```
...
AND (zip IN ($ziparrayimplode) OR all_zip=$allzip)
ORDER BY...
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.  I used AND (zip IN ($ziparrayimplode) AND all_zip=$allzip)